# Take hourly difference between two values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is what my data look like:

```
2020-10-09 13:31:00     2
2020-10-09 13:46:00     4
2020-10-09 14:01:00     10
2020-10-09 14:16:00     12
2020-10-09 14:31:00     13
2020-10-09 14:46:00     20
2020-10-09 15:01:00     25
2020-10-09 15:16:00     27
2020-10-09 15:31:00     30
2020-10-09 15:46:00     35
2020-10-09 16:01:00     40
```

What I need to get is the difference for the first value of each hour until the first value of the next full hour:

```
2020-10-09 13:00:00     2    -> 10 - 2  = 8
2020-10-09 14:00:00     4    -> 25 - 10 = 15
2020-10-09 15:00:00     10   -> 50 - 25 = 25
2020-10-09 16:00:00     12   -> 40 - ...
```

I really have problems with it and would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select convert(date, col1), datepart(hour, col1),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as col2,
       lead(max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end)) over (order by min(col1)) as next_col2,
       (lead(max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end)) over (order by min(col1)) -
        col2
       ) as diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, col1), datepart(hour, col1) order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
group by convert(date, col1), datepart(hour, col1);
```

Note:  This assumes that you have data for every hour (i.e. no gaps).  This is consistent with your sample data.  If this is not true, I would suggest that you ask a new question with a clearer explanation of what to do in this case.